# Query on Uncertainty Principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrostatics, electric-fields, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Consider a universe with only 1 electron. We can't know the position and momentum both of this electron, but we can measure the electric field at each point and since the only thing in the universe is the electron, knowing the electric field everywhere should give us the precise position as a function of time (and hence the momentum as well) — a violation of the uncertainty principle. What went wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In quantum mechanics, all of the dynamical variables of the system become operators, and their measurement is correspondingly subjected to a version of the Heisenberg uncertainty principle.

In quantum electrodynamics, the dynamical variables of the system are the electric and magnetic fields; as such, these are also operators and subject to the uncertainty principle.

This means that when you say

> but we can measure the electric field at each point

you're making an unwarranted assumption $-$ we *can't* measure the electric field to a precision that would allow this.